# _sysconfigdata error when trying to Freeze a Python 3.6.5 application

Tags: python, freeze

I'm trying to Freeze a Python 3.6.5 app into a standalone executable on Linux (Fedora 27 64 bit), using the default Python `freeze.py` utility. I have a checkout of Python 3.6.5 compiled, and I'm trying to freeze my application with the following (sanitized) commands:

```
LOCAL_PYTHON=(path to my compiled local python directory)
$LOCAL_PYTHON/python $LOCAL_PYTHON/Tools/freeze/freeze.py -p $LOCAL_PYTHON 
    -P $LOCAL_PYTHON -o frozen myapp.py
```

This freeze command seems to work fine, and generates the `myapp` executable as I would expect, but running the executable throws the following exception:

```
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "$LOCAL_PYTHON/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 971, in _find_and_load  
 return _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_) 
  File "$LOCAL_PYTHON/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked  
 module = _load_unlocked(spec)  
  File "$LOCAL_PYTHON/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 665, in _load_unlocked  
 spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "$LOCAL_PYTHON/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 807, in exec_module  
 exec(code, module.__dict__) 
  File "$LOCAL_PYTHON/Lib/site.py", line 544, in <module>
 main() 
  File "$LOCAL_PYTHON/Lib/site.py", line 530, in main 
 known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "$LOCAL_PYTHON/Lib/site.py", line 282, in addusersitepackages 
 user_site = getusersitepackages() 
  File "$LOCAL_PYTHON/Lib/site.py", line 258, in getusersitepackages 
 user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE  
  File "$LOCAL_PYTHON/Lib/site.py", line 248, in getuserbase
 USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')  
  File "$LOCAL_PYTHON/Lib/sysconfig.py", line 601, in get_config_var 
 return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "$LOCAL_PYTHON/Lib/sysconfig.py", line 550, in get_config_vars
 _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "$LOCAL_PYTHON/Lib/sysconfig.py", line 421, in _init_posix 
 _temp = __import__(name, globals(), locals(), ['build_time_vars'], 0) 
  File "$LOCAL_PYTHON/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 971, in _find_and_load  
 return _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_) 
  File "$LOCAL_PYTHON/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked  
 raise ModuleNotFoundError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)  
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m_linux_x86_64-linux-gnu'
```

My application works fine if I run it without freezing (e.g. `$LOCAL_PYTHON/python myapp.py`), and the same freeze command and app generate a working executable on Windows. Are there some platform specific Freeze parameters or environment variables that I'm missing?

Comment: @RichieHindle, can you do a simple file with a `print` statement and check if same happens with that also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was able to reproduce the issue by using docker. I ran a docker container using below

```
docker run -it fedora:27 bash
```

And then ran below commands to setup python from source

```
yum install -y git gcc unzip zip wget curl make cmake zlib-devel libsq3-devel readline-devel openssl-devel which vim findutils
mkdir py
cd py/
wget "https://github.com/python/cpython/archive/v3.6.5.zip"
unzip v3.6.5.zip
cd cpython-3.6.5/
./configure --with-debug
make -j8
```

After that I created a simple `app.py`

```
print('this is from app')
```

And then I ran

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LOCAL_PYTHON=/py/cpython-3.6.5/
$LOCAL_PYTHON/python $LOCAL_PYTHON/Tools/freeze/freeze.py -p $LOCAL_PYTHON -P $LOCAL_PYTHON -o frozen app.py
cd frozen/
make
./app
```

And I got below exception

```
[root@54ba4757d177 frozen]# ./app
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/py/cpython-3.6.5/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 971, in _find_and_load
    return _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)
  File "/py/cpython-3.6.5/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    module = _load_unlocked(spec)
  File "/py/cpython-3.6.5/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 665, in _load_unlocked
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "/py/cpython-3.6.5/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 807, in exec_module
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "/py/cpython-3.6.5/Lib/site.py", line 544, in <module>
    main()
  File "/py/cpython-3.6.5/Lib/site.py", line 530, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/py/cpython-3.6.5/Lib/site.py", line 282, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/py/cpython-3.6.5/Lib/site.py", line 258, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/py/cpython-3.6.5/Lib/site.py", line 248, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/py/cpython-3.6.5/Lib/sysconfig.py", line 601, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/py/cpython-3.6.5/Lib/sysconfig.py", line 550, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/py/cpython-3.6.5/Lib/sysconfig.py", line 421, in _init_posix
    _temp = __import__(name, globals(), locals(), ['build_time_vars'], 0)
  File "/py/cpython-3.6.5/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 971, in _find_and_load
    return _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)
  File "/py/cpython-3.6.5/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    raise ModuleNotFoundError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m_linux_x86_64-linux-gnu'
```

Same like you got. Then I ran `make install` to install python and tried again

```
make install -C /py/cpython-3.6.5/
```

And then the app again

```
[root@54ba4757d177 frozen]# ./app
this is from app
```

And it worked, so I understood that the issue is that the generated app assumes python is installed on machine. And then I found Gold in the form of

[Python freeze.py generated bin doesn't run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486414/python-freeze-py-generated-bin-doesnt-run)

I updated the `/py/cpython-3.6.5/Tools/freeze/makefreeze.py` file and added `Py_NoSiteFlag = 1;` before `PyImport_FrozenModules = _PyImport_FrozenModules;`.

[image: Change]

Of course I created the container again to make sure no python was installed on system. And then recompiled the app again and bingo!

```
[root@06284cc1ae0c frozen]# ./app
this is from app
```

To go one step further, I deleted all python source, build files and ran app again and it worked great

[image: Python App running after frozen]

Comment: This worked perfectly! I'm surprised that Freeze would assume by default that Python was installed on the target machine - is that not the point of Freeze?

Note - to get the final executable to work, I also had to set most of the core Python modules to build statically rather than dynamically in Setup/Modules.